# jQuery: Accessing Elements after adding them with Append

Tags: javascript, jquery

i append input in div:

```
$("#menuItems").append("<input type='button' id='"+$("#category").val()+"' class='menuItemDelete' value="+$("#category :selected").text()+" ><br>");
```

then i want to access element by class name but it does not give any responce.
i try this:

```
$(".menuItemDelete").click(function(){

    alert("abc");

});
```

and also try this:

```
$(".menuItemDelete").on("click", function(){

    alert("abc");

});
```

how can i access it ?

Comment: Do you get `abc` in alert when element is clicked?

Comment: @Tushar i do not get.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$("#menuItems").on("click",'.menuItemDelete', function(){
   alert("abc");
});
```

Consider to read this **[Event Delegation Concept](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** for dynamic element created like yours.

Answer (score 0):

Use [appendTo](https://api.jquery.com/appendTo) to get a reference back to the added elements

```
var els =$("<input type='button' id='"+$("#category").val()+"' class='menuItemDelete' value="+$("#category :selected").text()+" ><br>").appendTo("#menuItems");

els.filter('.menuItemDelete').click(...)
```

---

But since you are dealing with dynamic elements, you can also use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). The below handler can be added on dom ready and then there is no need to worry about when the dynamic elements are added

```
//on dom ready handler
$('#menuItems').on('click', '.menuItemDelete', function(){

});

//later somewhere else
$("#menuItems").append("<input type='button' id='"+$("#category").val()+"' class='menuItemDelete' value="+$("#category :selected").text()+" ><br>");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("click", ".menuItemDelete", function(){
    alert("abc");
});
```